# IMAP flatten folder structure

Tags: imap, directory, flatten

Anyone an idea how to flatten a certain folder in my IMAP account? There are literally hundreds of ((sub)sub)subfolders. It is a very old archive (from the time searching was a hell and subfolders were a good idea, yup, most of it last millenium) of which I want to add all message to my standard archive folder. Can't find anything on Google. I have root access to the VPS hosting the mailaccount. Directadmin and Roundcube are installed. It is a standard CentOS 7 Apache installation. Anyone know of any scripts, tools, Thunderbird plugins, or whatever, to do it? I am fluent in php but not python, but willing to look into it if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

./copy_nested_msgs.pl

http://www.athensfbc.com/imap-tools/public/copy_nested_msgs.tar.gz

-m folder  (parent folder whose subfolders you want to copy)
   -M folder  (destination folder where messages are to be copied)
   -S source server:port/user/password
   -D destinaton server:port/user/password
   -L logfile
   [-d] debug mode (optional)

You can copy the messages from source folders to destination folder on the same server or to another server.

Comment: Thank you! It took a few hours and I had to temporarily shut down the server firewall to do it, but it worked! Did you write that especially for me? It seems so, since you first didn't mention this script... If so: thank you many many times! And I  hope lots of other people will find it here and use it. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  I modified an existing script to do what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. Use the IMAP RENAME command to rename each of the folders in the structure.  For example:

Before

1 list "" *

* LIST (\UnMarked) "/" A

* LIST (\UnMarked) "/" A/B

* LIST (\UnMarked) "/" A/B/C

* LIST (\UnMarked) "/" A/B/C/D

* LIST (\UnMarked) "/" A/B/C/D/E

* LIST (\UnMarked) "/" A/B/C/D/E/F

* LIST (\UnMarked) "/" A/B/C/D/E/F/G

Sort the mailbox list so you do the most deeply-nested one first.

1 RENAME "A/B/C/D/E/F/G" "G"

2 RENAME "A/B/C/D/E/F" "F"

3 RENAME "A/B/C/D/E" "E"

4 RENAME "A/B/C/D" "D"

5 RENAME "A/B/C" "C"

6 RENAME "A/B" "B"

Afterwards...

1 list "" *

* LIST (\UnMarked) "/" A

* LIST (\UnMarked) "/" B

* LIST (\UnMarked) "/" C

* LIST (\UnMarked) "/" D

* LIST (\UnMarked) "/" E

* LIST (\UnMarked) "/" F

* LIST (\UnMarked) "/" G

A simple IMAP script can be written to do this.  I can post a link to mine but it's written in Perl.  You would have to convert it to the language of your choice but maybe it might be of some help.

Comment: Thank you. Please do! I have no IMAP command language experience. I do not know if your A B C D etc are meant to be literal names, variables, or something else. (There are multiple  hundreds of mail boxes, so manually naming them is not an option.) i literally do not understand at all what the above commands do. If you give me a few hints, I will Google the rest myself.

Comment: http://www.athensfbc.com/public/flatten_imap_folders.tar.gz.  It contains the Perl script and a README file that explains how to run it.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is awesome.

However, I was already wondering how a RENAME could do this. I think there is a misunderstanding? I need to get all the MESSAGES of all subfolders into the main folder. Your scipt seems to move all the SUBFOLDERS in stead of the messages. Am I right?

Is there an easy adaptation possible or is that a whole different ball park?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you want to do.  When you said wanted to flatten a folder I thought you meant flatten the subfolders.  Instead you want to move all messages from the subfolders into a single folder.  It can be done, of course, but that's another script to be written.

Comment: Yes, I wrote "I want to move all messages to the main folder" somehwere there but I agree that I could have been clearer. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Posted a link to another script as another answer to the question.  http://www.athensfbc.com/imap-tools/public/copy_nested_msgs.tar.gz